# Could not load type xxxx.from assembly , xxx Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=912f5a0b40d6a709'

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-config, httpmodule

I have a httpmodule class library which is implemented as shown in the following link

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Ashush/creating-a-sharepoint-portal-for-mobile/

I have added the dll to the GAC and created a web.config entry as follows :

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="MasterPageHttpModule" 
       type="MasterPageHttpModule.MasterPageHttpModule,MasterPageHttpModule, Version=1.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=912f5a0b40d6a709"/>
</modules>
```

I get the following error.

> Could not load type xxxx from
>   assembly xxxxx , Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx'.

I am not able to figure out where am i going wrong. Please help me with the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your module class may not be public OR an old version of your DLL may be still loaded in W3WC. Verify that your class is public and try IISRESET.